# Given $\sigma,\tau\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, is there an $\alpha\in L$ such that $\sigma\alpha=\alpha$ and $\tau\alpha\neq\alpha$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension with group $G$. Given two elements $\sigma,\tau\in G$,

Is there an element $\alpha\in L$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ and $\tau(\alpha)\neq\alpha$?

This is not homework; I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$(You assume that neither $\sigma$ nor $\tau$ are the identity, I guess - see the comment by drhab below.)

Not necessarily. Let $K = \Q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive root of $1$.

Let $L = K(\sqrt[3]{2})$, the splitting field over $K$ of $x^{3} - 2$.

The Galois group is cyclic of order $3$, say $\Span{\sigma}$. Clearly the only elements fixed by $\sigma$ are those of $K$, and the same holds for $\tau = \sigma^{2}$.

Comment: You're right, I will add that I assume also that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are both different from the identity, otherwise is somewhat trivial.

Comment: Well, I have just quoted it, please leave it be!

Comment: Oops, you refer to my vanished comment now. Let me put it back: "how about the identity on $L$?"